# Forms retaining values after closing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb6-migration

Throughout our program, forms are opened like this:

```
FormName.SomeValue = 10
FormName.ShowDialog()
```

rather than the usual

```
Dim myForm As New FormName
myForm.SomeValue = 10
myForm.ShowDialog()
```

*(There is nothing we could do about this - this was done automatically by the Visual Studio VB6 --> VB.Net converter)*

The problem is that when forms are closed, they seem to not really be closed, only hidden - if I add some text to a textbox and close/reopen the form, the text is still there, rather than the textbox being cleared like normal.  This is presumably because the form always uses the same instance.

**Is there any easy way to fix this** other than going through the entire program and creating a new form instance for every `ShowDialog()` call *(there are hundreds)*?

We considered resetting every control in every form's `Load` event, but that would still be a pain, so we figured we'd ask if there's a simpler way first.

Comment: You are going to have to edit the code and call Dispose() after the ShowDialog() call.  Using the *Using* statement is better.  While you're at it, getting rid of the horrid VB6 'type name = object reference' habit is a good idea.  It blows up bad whenever you start using threads.

Comment: @Hans: I have no idea what habit you're talking about, I come from a C# world.  I've never done any VB6.

Comment: My condolences.  Search the code base for DoEvents and SendKeys to see what you're up against.

Comment: What you are dealing with is called the form's "default instance" and is a carry over from the VB6 days.  It is not recommended practice to use it.  You may not want to hear it, but the best long-term strategy for your code base is to rewrite the form initializers the correct way than to do some hacky workaround in the form Load() events.  You may hate it now, but you will appreciate it the next time you have to work on this code.  You can probably even put together a snippet to do most of the typing for you.

Comment: @Steve: Thank you for the information and advice; that is the same realization I came to, so that is what I ended up doing *(it took about 2 hours..)*.  If you make that an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are dealing with is called the form's "default instance" and is a carry over from the VB6 days. It is not recommended practice to use it. You may not want to hear it, but the best long-term strategy for your code base is to rewrite the form initializers the correct way than to do some hacky workaround in the form Load() events. You may hate it now, but you will appreciate it the next time you have to work on this code. You can probably even put together a snippet to do most of the typing for you.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class MyForm: Form{

   private static MyForm myForm = null;

   public static DialogResult ShowDialog(bool newForm){
          if(newForm)
          {
                if(myForm != null) 
                    myForm.Dispose();
                myForm= new MyForm();
          }
          return myForm.ShowDialog();
   }

   public static DialogResult ShowDialog(){
          return ShowDialog(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: concepts does not have languages :)

Comment: This should work in VB, everything can be converted to VB quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
How to display the form using the Using statement

```
Using formName AS New FormName
    formName.SomeValue = 10
    formName.ShowDialog()
End Using
```

<strike>It appears from the code displayed here that there is now a `static ShowDialog` call that was added to your `FormName` class. You should be able to edit just this method to `dispose` of the old form and create and display the new one. This would help you avoid changing code all over the place, just in the one location.</strike>

Comment: This is VB.Net, not C#.  In VB.Net, unlike C#, you can apparently reference an automatically-created global instance of any form using the form's class's name.  I don't know what this is called, so I don't know what to google for this problem.

Comment: My bad, didn't realize that VB did that. If this is the case, then you are going to need to follow @Hans comment. You need to add dispose calls, and I would recommend doing that via a `Using` statement.

Comment: @your edit: Yes, I already mentioned we *could* replace every invocation of `ShowDialog()` in the program, but that would be a huge hassle.  Also, `Using` is not necessary for Forms as they are automatically disposed of when they are closed.

Comment: @Blue I know you don't want to change the code, but you are going to have to - code migration is not always "automagic". Forms are not automatically disposed when they are closed, you have to dispose of them manually. If they were disposed then you could not guarantee access to the properties of the dialog after it was closed (i.e. open file dialog).

Comment: @pstrjds: Dispose is not the same as garbage collected :) Dispose is indeed called when the form is closed; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw58wzka.aspx

Comment: @Blue - you did not read that correctly "Dispose will be called automatically if the form is shown using the Show method. If another method such as ShowDialog is used, or the form is never shown at all, you must call Dispose yourself within your application." You are using the ShowDialog method. It is only called if shown via Show. If you just create it and don't show it, or you call ShowDialog you have to dispose of it :)

Answer (score 1):

#### You asked for easy way to fix this:

Change your `ShowDialog()` procedure/function calls in the following way:

```
   AS PROCEDURE                       |   AS FUNCTION
                                      | 
    FormName.ShowDialog()             |    r = FormName.ShowDialog()
    FormName.ShowDialog()             |    r = FormName.ShowDialog()
                                      |
   CHANGE TO                          |   CHANGE TO
                                      |
    Call New FormName.ShowDialog()    |    r = New FormName.ShowDialog()
    Call New FormName.ShowDialog()    |    r = New FormName.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is super late but-

```
Form1.Dispose()
```

works for me. It resets the textboxes.

Comment: This method also works for me. I add this on my form close event  `Me.Dispose()`. So far I haven't had any issues using this.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the question is about clearing text boxes then I would have Cleared all of them RECURSIVELY

   ```
     For Each Control in Controls
         If Control is type of TextBox
         Control.Clear
     Next
   ```
2. If you are binding controls by any DATASOURCE I would suggest to clear the Datasource and REBIND
3. Override the ShowDialog() Method.